# New-NetFirewallRule;Espacios de nombres no valido

Tags: powershell

Estoy teniendo un problema al ejecutar un script en powershell, me sale lo siguiente error al ejecutarlo.

```
New-NetFirewallRule;Espacios de nombres no valido
```

no se a que puede ser debido.

Comment: Creo que es necesario que des algo más de contexto sobre el script que ejecutas, pues es posible que esto se deba a dónde está la instrucción que muestras dentro del script

Comment: Esta dentro de una funcion, de todas formas lo probe con la consola de powershell y sigue dándome el mismo error

Comment: Prueba corriendo la consola como Admin.

Comment: tampoco funciona